# PowerShell - Certificate is not accessible to the current user

Tags: powershell

I'm using the Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module on MacOS and running the next command:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateFilePath "./certificate.pfx" -CertificatePassword "123" -AppID "appid" -Organization "organization@email.com"
```

And I get this message:

> Get-ConnectionContext: Certificate is not accessible to the current user.

I installed my certificate in the Mac KeyChain and it still doesn't work.

Did someone face this issue before? Thanks!

Comment: out of curiosity, can you use the full path instead of the relative path instead?

Comment: I changed it to an absolute path and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the certificate was wrong and led to a file that didn't exist.
Fixing the path solves this issue.

Comment: Thank you for this. I would have expected `"Cannot find path './certificate.pfx' because it does not exist"` instead of the error message you actually received. I am sure others will find this useful in the future.